# Render Error Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ios-simulator, render

I am trying to import an image on react-native, from the `assets` folder,(contains all the images). However the images are not compiling when I export them on the IOS-simulator. I think it is important to add that my `assets` file (that contains all the images), is a read-only file. I've attached an image on the bottom of what the assets-folder looks like on my end. In addition to that picture, I have also attached screenshots of the two errors I am experiencing with the IOS-simulator.

Thank You for your time!

Now, for better clarity here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';

import  { ImageBackround, StyleSheet, View, Image, Text} from 'react-native';

function WelcomeScreen(props){
    return(
        <>
        <ImageBackround
        style={styles.background}
        source={require('./assets/icon.png')}
        >
        <View style={styles.logoContainer}>

        <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('./assets/favicon.png')}/>
        <Text> Sell what you dont need!</Text>
        </View>
        <View style ={styles.registerButton}></View>
        < View style= {styles.loginButton}></View>
        </ImageBackround>
        </>
    )
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    background: {
        flex:1,
        alignItems: "center" ,
    
    },
    loginButton: {
        width: "100%",
        height: 70,
        backgroundColor: "#4ecdc4",

    },
    logo: {
        width: 100,
        height: 100,

    },
    logoContainer: {
        position: "absolute",
        top: 70,
        alignItems:"center",
    
    },
    registerButton: {
        width: "100%",
        height: 70,
        backgroundColor: "#4ecdc4"
    },
});



export default WelcomeScreen;
```

Here Ive attached in order, the image of the `assets` file, and the 2 errors that the Ios-simulator is giving me:

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try creating a file inside assets which exports all images and call it from your WelcomeScreen.

create index.js file inside assets folder like this

```
export const Images ={
   adaptive:require('./adaptive.png'),
   favicon:require('./favicon.png'),
   icon:require('./icon.png'),
   splash:require('./splash.png')
}
```

and change your WelcomeScreen like this

```
import React from 'react';
import  { ImageBackround, StyleSheet, View, Image, Text} from 'react-native';
import {Images} from './assets';

function WelcomeScreen(props){
    return(
        <>
        <ImageBackround
        style={styles.background}
        source={Images.icon}
        >
        <View style={styles.logoContainer}>

        <Image style={styles.logo} source={Images.favicon}/>
        <Text> Sell what you dont need!</Text>
        </View>
        <View style ={styles.registerButton}></View>
        < View style= {styles.loginButton}></View>
        </ImageBackround>
        </>
    )
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    background: {
        flex:1,
        alignItems: "center" ,
    
    },
    loginButton: {
        width: "100%",
        height: 70,
        backgroundColor: "#4ecdc4",

    },
    logo: {
        width: 100,
        height: 100,

    },
    logoContainer: {
        position: "absolute",
        top: 70,
        alignItems:"center",
    
    },
    registerButton: {
        width: "100%",
        height: 70,
        backgroundColor: "#4ecdc4"
    },
});



export default WelcomeScreen;
```

Comment: I did that, however now it is stuck on the splash screen(white blank screen).

Comment: can you show me your navigation file and root screen

Comment: I re-launched my project and am still experiencing the same error. So, i dont have a blank screen issue anymore. Where would i find the navigation file and root screen? Thanks for your fast response time, appreciate it

Comment: The error on VS-code. 
It says this:

This error is located at:
    in WelcomeScreen (created by App)
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in DevAppContainer (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer.

Comment: You have only welcome screen?
No navigation setup?

Comment: I haven't made a navigation component, because i'm currently following Mosh hamedani's react-native course, and he didn't make one either.

Comment: If i do create one, you think the problem will be solved?

Comment: No, error is not because of not using navigation. I just asked for clarifying.
So you have only welcome screen.
Can you share your project structure like you showed your assets folder above and also updated WelcomeScreen which caused error.

Comment: Sounds good, I just updated the post. Its the 4th picture

Comment: Oh so this is an expo project.
Sorry I don't have much experience in expo.
Here is reference to folder structure of expo project : [expo-folder-and-file-structure](https://ckmobile.medium.com/expo-folder-and-file-structure-872661bdf339)
Try updating your code like that.
Good Luck.

Comment: Yeah, this project is an expo project.